# Intellij - Display git branches as directories

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there a way to display the git branches in Intellij not as a simple list but rather a directory-structure, as in SourceTree? E.g. **feature/branch1** would be displayed as folder **feature**, branch **branch1**.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open Branches Pane please go to Git Toolwindow, open Log tab, and on a left side, there should be "Branches" button, please click on it to get a desire view.

For more see:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html#BranchesPane